# What is the difference between String.Substring and Mid?

Tags: vb.net

I am really confused between `Mid` and `Substring` in VB.NET. Can anyone help me understand the difference with the help of a program? It will be really appreciated.

Comment: hi, are you referring to multiple document interface (MDI)?

Comment: Are you asking about the MID string function that was superseeded by SubString() or MDI as in the Multiple Document Interface?

Comment: no i am referring to MDI functions

Comment: yes hursey  MID string function that was superseeded by SubString()

Comment: You don't need to know the difference. `Mid` is a VB6 holdover that you should not be using at all so how it works is irrelevant. If you want to extract a substring then call `Substring`. That's it, that's all.

Comment: Don't spam tags. If you had read the description of the MDI tag then you'd know that MDI is not what you're even asking about - not that it should require that to know what you're asking about - and what has this question got to do with ADO.NET? Try putting some thought and effort into your questions, including what tags are and are not relevant.

Answer (score 5):

You can read the documentation [for Mid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.mid?view=net-5.0) and  [for Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0)

The biggest difference arises from Mid being a legacy adapter function intended either to help VB6 code work if pasted into a vb.net project, or to provide VB6 programmers with some familiar functionality while they switch to using the modern .NET equivalent (Substring)

As a legacy function, Mid adopts the VB6 notions of strings being one-based indexing, rather than zero based (used by nearly everything else .NET) so anything you Mid should have a start parameter that is 1 greater than anything you Substring

```
Mid("Hellow World",1,5) 'returns Hello
Substring("Hellow World",0,5) 'returns Hello
```

Substring has a corollary, Remove, which removes chars after a certain point like Left used to. Ditching Left/Mid/Right in favour of Substring/Remove makes it easier to understand what to use/what will happen if the string passed in is in a right-to-left language

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference is that Mid doesn't throw any exceptions, while substring will throw if any of your indexes are out of range.

```vb
   Dim s = "this".Substring(100, 5000) ' this throws "ArgumentOutOfRange" exception
   Dim str = Mid("This", 100, 5000) ' string will equal string.empty
```

This makes Mid more convenient in some circumstances, and if you're already using Microsoft.VisualBasic (which is not just a legacy namespace, it's even available in .net core 7) from a previous project or some other need, I wouldn't recommend changing.

If you just don't like VB for some reason, you could create an extension method and make it behave however you like.