# Translating decryption function from VB6 to C#

Tags: c#, vb6, code-conversion

I am updating code from VB6 to C#. I have a requirement of backwards compatibility. So files encrypted in the VB6 version need to be able to be decrypted in the C# version. So far I am unable to decrypt the files from the VB6 version.

The VB6 decrypt code is

```vb
Public Function DecryptFile(File() As Byte) As Byte()
    Dim op1 As Integer
    Dim i As Double
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim M As Double
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim The_Password As String
    pwork = Swap(Expand_Process("Password"))
    l = Len(Trim(pwork))
    M = UBound(File)
    k = 1
    For i = 0 To M
        j = File(i) - Asc(Mid(pwork, k, 1))
        If j < 0 Then
            j = j + 256
        End If
        File(i) = j
        k = k + 1
        If k > l Then
           k = 1
        End If
    Next i
    DecryptFile = File
End Function

Public Function Swap(The_Data As String)
    Dim Y, x As Integer
    Dim rest As String
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim wrk As String
    rest = ""
    x = Len(The_Data) / 2
    For Y = 1 To x
      wrk = Mid(The_Data, Y * 2, 1) & Mid(The_Data, Y * 2 - 1, 1)
      rest = rest & wrk
    Next Y
    Y = Len(The_Data) - (x * 2)
    If Y > 0 Then
       rest = rest & Right(The_Data, Y)
    End If
    Swap = rest
End Function

Public Function Expand_Process(The_Data As String) As String
    Dim p1 As Double
    Dim p2 As Integer
    Dim rd() As Variant
    Dim m1 As Integer
    Dim m2 As Integer
    Dim dwork As String
    rd = Array(7, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2)
    p1 = Round(Len("Password") / 5, 0)
    dwork = ""
    For p2 = 1 To 5
        m1 = rd(p2) * p1
        m2 = m1 - (p1 - 1)
        dwork = dwork & Mid(The_Data, m1, p1)
    Next p2
    Expand_Process = dwork
End Function
```

The C# code I've translated it to is

```cs
public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] file)
{
    int op1;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
    double m;
    int r;
    string pword = Swap(Expand_Process("Password"));
    l = pword.Trim().Length;
    m = file.GetUpperBound(0);
    k = 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++)
    {
        string mid = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(pword, k, 1);
        int asc = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Asc(mid);
        j = file[i] - asc;
        if (j < 0)
        {
            j += 256;
        }
        file[i] = Convert.ToByte(j);
        k++;
        if (k > l)
        {
            k = 1;
        }
    }
    return file;
}

private string Expand_Process(string data)
{
    double p1;
    int[] rd;
    double m1;
    double m2;
    rd = [7, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2];
    p1 = Math.Round((double)("Password".Length / 5), 0);
    string dwork = "";
    for (int p2 = 1; p2 <= 5; p2++)
    {
        m1 = rd[p2] * p1;
        m2 = m1 - (p1 - 1);
        dwork += dwork + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(data, (int)m1, (int)p1);
    }
    return dwork;
}

private string Swap(string data)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    string rest;
    int r;
    string wrk;
    rest = "";
    x = data.Length / 2;
    for (y = 1; y <= x; y++)
    {
        wrk = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(data, y * 2, 1) + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(data, y * 2 - 1, 1);
        rest += wrk;
    }
    y = data.Length - (x * 2);
    if (y > 0)
    {
        rest += Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right(data, y);
    }
    return rest;
}
```

I am assuming the issue lies in the difference in typing between the two languages. For example, the line `File(i) = j` in VB6 cannot be written directly into C# as `file[i] = j` due to the file array being bytes. I tried using `Convert.ToByte(j)`, but I'm not sure if this is an accurate translation.

If you could help me out identifying the issues with my translated code such that I can decrypt files that were encrypted with the old VB6 code, I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: You may consider starting by identifying the proper data types. [VB6 data types](https://www.developerfusion.com/article/32/data-types/) and [Integral numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types). I also wouldn't attempt to _convert_ the code, but rather re-write it in C# such that it gives the desired result.

Comment: What is the size of an integer?  I would step through code on both old and new at same time and compare results.  Make sure you are using ReadAllBytes method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=net-8.0

Comment: @jdweng You will learn the sizes of the integers if you click the links in the [comment posted 10 minutes before yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78094142/translating-decryption-function-from-vb6-to-c-sharp#comment137675936_78094142).

Comment: @GSerg : I know the answer.  Vb6 is 16 bits while c# is 32 bits.

Comment: @jdweng No need to ask then.

Comment: @jdweng I am using ReadAllBytes, thank you. I realize I missed that part of the code in my question. I am actually trying to decrypt a bitmap; and the decrypt method does complete "successfully". If I try to read the image from the decrypted byte array, I get an ```ArugmentException``` from Image.FromStream.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my translation

```
       static byte[] DecryptFile(byte[] File)
        {
            byte j;
            int k;
            int l;
            double M;
            int r;

            string pwork = Swap("Password");

            l = pwork.Trim().Length;
            k = 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < File.Length; i++)
            {
                byte chr = (byte)(pwork.Substring(k, 1).First());
                j = (byte)(File[i] - chr);
                File[i] = j;
                k = k + 1;
                if (k > l) k = 1;
            }
            return File;
        }
        static string Swap(string The_Data)
        {
            int x;
            string rest = "";
            int r;
            char wrk;

            x = The_Data.Length / 2;
            for (int Y = 1; Y <= x; Y++)
            {
                wrk = (char)(The_Data[Y * 2] & The_Data[Y * 2 - 1]);
                rest += wrk;

                Y = The_Data.Length - (x * 2);
                if (Y > 0) rest = rest + The_Data.Substring(The_Data.Length - Y);
            }
            return rest;
         }
```

Comment: The problem is, in VB6 strings are 1-based while in c# they are 0-based. See [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66469418/2516718). VB6 code is doing `k = 1` and then `Mid(pword, k, 1)` so I guess you need to pass `k-1` as first argument when calling c# `Substring()` method.